# Redirect stdin into stdin

Tags: bash, redirect, stdin

Is it possible in Bash to redirect `STDIN` into `STDIN`? Like for example this:

```
echo -n rain > < `echo bow`
```

Now, I do realise that the above code is nonsense (it's more like pseudocede). What could be the proper way of doing it?

Comment: STDIN is still STDIN, it doesn't need to be redirected. You may include in your question your real goal you want to achieve.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you really want from your example. It seems the following may work for you `echo -n rain $(echo bow)`

Comment: No no. I want one STDIN going into another STDIN. Two different STDINs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output of two programs to a third like so:

```
{ echo -n rain; echo bow; } | cat
```

That's my best guess at what you're asking.